# replacing employees missing postcode by the company or colleague postcode

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, first, one for employees which has 'employee_id','company_id' and postcode. the second table has company_id,company_postcode.

the postcode is missing from a large number of employees or because of a bug in the platform customer were able to enter any value in postcode section so it could be a street name, phone number, date of birth or even something like 000000.
I want if possible to replace the missing/wrong postcode by the company_post code and if the company postcode is also missing or wrong I need it to be replaced by one of their colleague postcodes.
thank you, Eric, I agree with you and sorry for not sharing my queries,

```
SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.company_id,
    e.postcode,
    c.reg_address_postcode,
    postcode2,
    CASE
        WHEN
            postcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
                OR postcode IS NOT NULL
                OR postcode != ''
        THEN
            postcode
        WHEN
            postcode REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
                OR postcode IS NULL
                OR postcode = ''
                AND c.reg_address_postcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
                OR c.reg_address_postcode IS NOT NULL
                OR c.reg_address_postcode != ''
        THEN
            c.reg_address_postcode
        WHEN
            postcode REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
                OR postcode IS NULL
                OR postcode = ''
                AND c.reg_address_postcode REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
                OR c.reg_address_postcode IS NULL
                OR c.reg_address_postcode = ''
        THEN
            postcode2
    END AS new_postcode
FROM
    employees e
        LEFT JOIN
    companies c ON e.company_id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(e.id),
            e.company_id,
            TRIM(postcode) postcode2,
            c.reg_address_postcode
    FROM
        employees e
    LEFT JOIN companies c ON e.company_id = c.id
    WHERE
        e.postcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]'
            AND (e.postcode != ''
            OR e.postcode IS NOT NULL)
            AND (TRIM(e.postcode) < 4
            OR TRIM(e.postcode) > 10)
    GROUP BY company_id) o ON e.company_id = o.company_id
```

Comment: What have you tried so far???  SO is not a free coding service.  You post your query.  If it doesn't work, someone can help you.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you, @ericI haven't included my queries because none of them worked, whoever, I've just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `CASE`. `AND` takes precedence over `OR`.  So your code

```
WHEN postcode REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
    OR postcode IS NULL
    OR postcode = ''
    AND c.reg_address_postcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
    OR c.reg_address_postcode IS NOT NULL
    OR c.reg_address_postcode != ''
THEN
    c.reg_address_postcode
```

is treated as

```
WHEN postcode REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
    OR postcode IS NULL
    OR (postcode = ''
    AND c.reg_address_postcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]$')
    OR c.reg_address_postcode IS NOT NULL
    OR c.reg_address_postcode != ''
THEN
    c.reg_address_postcode
```

Which I am sure not what you want.  Try to put bracket  in your `OR`

```
WHEN (postcode REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
    OR postcode IS NULL
    OR postcode = '')
    AND (c.reg_address_postcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]$'
    OR c.reg_address_postcode IS NOT NULL
    OR c.reg_address_postcode != '')
THEN
    c.reg_address_postcode
```

Comment: thank you Eric, I have tried it but didn't work, the New_postcode column is exactly the same as postcode